# Redirect to different ViewControllers according to segue

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I'm new to iOS and its developing.I have tableview and two cells.when i press the cell i want to redirected to viewController object.i want to do it according to segue identifier.please find below the code i used.

```
   #import "Essentialinfocontroller.h"

    @interface Essentialinfocontroller ()
    {

        NSMutableArray * titlearray;

        NSMutableArray * subtitilearray;

    }
    @end

    @implementation Essentialinfocontroller

    @synthesize info;


    - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
    {
        self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil\];
        if (self) {

        }
        return self;
    }

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        self.info.delegate=self;
        self.info.dataSource=self;

        titlearray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Custom",@"Department Of Immigration",@"Foriegn Currency Regulations",@"Sri Lankan Embassies" ,@"Sri Lankan Visa",@"When You Are There..", nil];

    }

    -(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView

    {

        return 1;

    }

    -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

    {

        return [titlearray count];

    }

    -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

    {

        static NSString * cellidentifier=@"cell";

        UITableViewCell * cell= [info dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellidentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];



        cell.textLabel.text =[titlearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        return cell;



    }

    -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
    {
        if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"custom"])
        {
            //redirected to Viewcontroller custome
        }
        else if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"depart"])
        {
            // redirected to viewController Department
        }
    }

@end][1]
```

[image: My story Board]

Comment: When you press a cell on your tableView, you need to navigate to another viewController?

Comment: @GenieWanted yap thats i want.but i want to do it according to segue identifier

Comment: Did you try didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method?

Answer (score 1):

Use this method at the point from where you want to segue to a new Controller.

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"yourSegueIdentifierName" sender:nil];
```

This method will automatically trigger the `prepareForSegue` method as soon as the above statement is encountered and as mentioned in your `prepareForSegue` method, you are checking the segue identifier names using if..else so that should do it.

Follow these steps :

1. Use the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` delegate method to check which row in the tableView was clicked. This is to know which segue identifier are we going to use for the particular row. Now you have your selectedRow index. So we go to next step.
2. After knowing which row is being clicked, use this function for redirecting to the appropriate controller with the segue Identifer from your source Controller.

   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"yourSegueIdentifierName" sender:nil];
3. As soon as your `performSegueWithIdentifier` is called, the `prepareForSegue` will be called immediately after it. And in that, as you have done right now, you can check the segue Identifier and use your own logic in that if...else code.

Comment: then how i redirected to viewController according to segue ? please find above my story board

Comment: Use your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` to check which row was clicked and then in that function , you can use the above function that I have shown. So basically it will trigger a particular segue with given identifier for whichever row is clicked.

Comment: i have connected correctly .could you please explain me more.i didn't get you.

Comment: I assume you have given those segues an identifier. Now the next step is to use `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` delegate method to check which row is tapped. In that method, you need to identify which row was clicked and based on that, you need to use `performSegueWithIdentifier` that I have shown above. So basically if row no. 1 is tapped, a segue with identifier XYZ will be called and if row no.2 is tapped, segue with identifier ABC will be called.

Comment: The flow is like : Check which row is tapped in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`and then just use appropriate `performSegueWithIdentifier` for that row. The `prepareForSegue` will be called automatically after `performSegueWithIdentifier.`